# Regex, exclusive string end matching

Tags: regex

New to regex, not done learning everything yet.

When trying to match the a string that ends in, let's say, 1-5 occurrences of character a at the end one can match it with the pattern "a{1-5}$". Easy peasy, works.

What if I want it NOT to match if there are 6 or more occurrences but still have 1-5.

"[^a]+a{1-5}$" doesn't work properly because it then requires another character before a-pattern.

I want "aaaaaa" not to work and "aaaaa" to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dependent on the flavor you can use a [negative look behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookbehind):

```
(?<!a)a{1,5}$
```

Alternative you can use:

```
(?:[^a]|^)a{1,5}$
```

Which will match `[^a]` or start of string before your 1 to 5 a's